# Using like operator in SSRS Expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2014

I have a tablix with following results.

[SSRS Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZJle.jpg)

Since i am learning SSRS. i wonder how to Sum line total with respect to product name. Since product name has duplicate values but it has only M and Xl difference. If i use row group it won't total like i expected since it has M and Xl difference. I wonder how to write an expression for the total. 
The desired result set

```
May 31 2011     S043659      Long-Sleeve Logo jerse M     3      $86.52
                             Long-Sleeve Logo jersey XL    1      $28.84
                                                           Total  $115.36
                             mountain bike socks M        6       $34.20
```

i used this expression but giving me an error.

```
 `IIF((Fields!Product.value = Previous(Fields!Product.value),Sum(Fields!linetotal.value))`
```

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a few things wrong with your expression.

The IIF doesn't have a 3rd argument for the ELSE value. In this case, you'd want to use 0. So the expression would be IIF the fields match then LineTotal Else 0.

You want to have the SUM on the outside of the IIF, otherwise it will only SUM one row.

The matching without the size is trickier. I have it trim off the last 4 characters to exclude the size for a match - it may not work depending on your other Product names.

```
=SUM(IIF(LEFT(Fields!Product.value, LEN(Fields!Product.value) - 4) = LEFT(Previous(Fields!Product.value), LEN(Fields!Product.value) - 4), Fields!linetotal.value, 0))
```

The expression reads the SUM of (IF the Product matches the Previous Product then the Line Total else 0).

All this being said, it would actually be easy to crate a parent group and GROUP BY on the parent product. Unfortunately, your data uses a comma to separate one type (jersey) by size but a space in another (socks) so I don't see how to do it. If they all had a comma, I would create a **Calculated Field** on the dataset to use the product-line up to the comma.

```
=LEFT(Fields!Product.value, INSTR(Fields!Product.value, ",") - 1)
```

IF your Product line is either a comma or space to separate, you might be able to use this for your Calculated Field:

```
=LEFT(Fields!Product.value, 
    IIF(INSTR(Fields!Product.value, ",") > 0, 
        INSTR(Fields!Product.value, ",") - 1,
        InStrRev(Fields!Product.value, " ") - 1) )
```

Comment: I removed comma from my data but i used your expression and i still get error:The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox71.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ uses a Previous function in an outer aggregate.  Previous functions cannot be specified as nested aggregates.

Comment: from the total text box i used your expression=SUM(IIF(LEFT(Fields!Product.value, LEN(Fields!Product.value) - 4) = LEFT(Previous(Fields!Product.value), LEN(Fields!Product.value) - 4), Fields!linetotal.value, 0)) but still having the problem  Previous functions cannot be specified as nested aggregates

Comment: Ugh - I forgot about the aggregation issue. I think the best way would be to add the calculated field and add a GROUP BY the new Product field. Unfortunately, it will only work when you have a comma or a space at the end for the size of each product.

Comment: so you mean it's not going to possible? @hannover fist

Comment: @Jennifer - it's not going to work with the expression. I think it would work with the Calculated Field and the extra GROUPING based on it. But that would require your Product name to have a comma or space separating the size.

Comment: I would leave the commas and spaces in as there were originally and then use @HannoverFist 's final code sample as the actual group expression.